# 2 category intersection with PetScan not working?

Tags: wikipedia, wiktionary

I'm trying to create an intersection between two categories on Wiktionary using PetScan (http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php), but I can't get it to work. What I've read says it *should* be possible to do, so I'm pretty sure the error is user-generated! (ie; I don't know what I'm doing.)

Basically I want to generate a list of entry links that are tagged in both of the following categories:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_terms_spelled_with_kanji_with_kun_readings
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Japanese_terms_spelled_with_kanji_with_on_readings

The first has 2009 subcategories and the second, 1035 subcategories.... way too many to check manually. If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=5011942 ?

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know what I was doing wrong, but this is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=5011942 — for articles
- https://petscan.wmflabs.org/?psid=5011963 — for subcategories

Most likely, you've just forgot to increase value of the "Depth" field in GUI.